# Given a bitonic array, we need to find the peak element

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, bufferedreader, binary-search

We are given a bitonic array, i.e an array of elements which is first increasing and then maybe decreasing. We need to find the maximum element in the array.

```
Input:
2
9
1 15 25 45 42 21 17 12 11
5
1 45 47 50 5

Output:
45
50
```

My code for the approach is something like this :

```
private static int findMax(int[] arr,int size){
             int low = 0;
             int high = size-1;
              while(low<=high){
               int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
                if(arr[mid] > arr[mid+1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]){
                  return arr[mid];
                }else if(arr[mid-1]>arr[mid]){
                  high = mid-1;
                }else{
                  low = mid+1;
              }
            }
             return -1;
          }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
             try {
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
              String line = br.readLine();
              String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s");
              int testCases = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
              String[] strs1;
              while(testCases>0){
                 strs1 = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s");
                 int size = Integer.parseInt(strs1[0]);
                 String[] stringArray = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s");
                 int[] arr = new int[size];
                 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                     arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
                 }
                 int ans = findMax(arr,size);
                 System.out.println(ans);
                 testCases--;
                 } 
            } catch(Exception e){} 
    }
```

Though it works fine for smaller inputs it seems to be not working for larger inputs and I don't understand the reason. The error that i'm getting is:

```
Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
10041
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 27.................

Its Correct output is:
10041

And Your Code's output is:
```

I am unable to understand why it works pretty fine for smaller inputs and also if I change the input size to say 1000 and pass an array with 1000 elements and 978 max then it works fine but I'm not able to submit it. The platform I'm using is Geeksforgeeks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing correct bitonic Array? If not then you need to also write check function for a bitonic array. Then your code may work. Sharing my code below for reference for finding Max Number in an Array.

```
private static int findMax(int[] arr){
    int low = 0, high = arr.length -1, mid;
    while(low <= high){
      mid = (low + high)/2;
      if(arr[mid] > arr[mid+1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]) {
        return arr[mid];
      } else if(arr[mid-1] > arr[mid] && arr[mid] > arr[mid+1]) {
        high = mid-1;
      } else if(arr[mid+1] > arr[mid] && arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]) {
        low = mid+1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Sharing code for checking array is Bitonic or not, which gives time complexity as O(log n)

```
public static int checkBitonicArr(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    int initialCount = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            continue;
        else break;
    }
    if (i == arr.length - 1) return 0;
    for (j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) continue;
        else break;
    }
    if (j != arr.length - 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can test it using `checkBitonicArr(a) == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"`

Comment: this is so helpful!!